# FLutter check if Textfield controller is empty

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, textformfield

i have a question in flutter about a Textfield and the controller attribute.

I have a site add_new_currency_screen.dart,
for the beginning i have textfields like:
name, amount, price, startDate and endDate.

Now my problem.
The endDate is always "empty" if i open the "add screen", if i enter a startDate the Enddate should be added by a year.

```
 TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'EndDate'),
                      controller: _endDateController..text = DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(_pickedStartDate.add(Duration(days: 365))),
                      enabled: false,
                    ),
```

The problem is im getting an error "add" was called on "null"

in controller i can't use if else,
and _endDateController.text == null ? "empty" : DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(_pickedStartDate.add(Duration(days: 365))), does not work to....

How can i check or how can i fix this, that if the startDate is picked, the controller in the endDate is doing the thing, else, just dont use the "add"

hope i could explain it correctly and someone can help me :)

thanks all,
best regards
Thommy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get "add" was called on null, then the problem has to do with `_pickedStartDate`

So perhaps try something like:

```
controller: _endDateController..text = _pickedStartDate != null ? DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(_pickedStartDate.add(Duration(days: 365))) : '',
```

Comment: On the first start/ opening the DetailsPage the _pickedStartDate ist always null, because in this form i have to choose / Pick a date, after i picked a date, on a new field, the pickedDate should be added by the duration..

I will try ur solution later in the evening :) thnaks